# How to call trigger with double selector?

Tags: jquery, triggers

How to call trigger function in jQuery for this event, with double selector?

```
$("#start").on("click", '.remove-selected', function ()
{
    // ...
}
```

Because this is not working `$("#start").trigger("click", '.remove-selected');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can trigged click event with

```
$("#start .remove-selected").click();
```